# What is the best architecture with Firebase, android and backend?

Tags: android, api, firebase, backend

What is the best architecture?
I have to use Firebase, Mobile (android / ios) and Web(angular). I would like to build an API so that services are consumed from mobile and web, but we have not Firebase backend. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For your case, if you want to avoid tightly coupled code, then I suggest you to see "**Clean Architecture**" by  Robert Cecil Martin.

Fernando Cejas has written a nice article about it and used in conjunction with MVP to separate Presentation from Business Logic. You can refer to his article,link given:
[Architecting Android…The clean way?](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/)

If it seems more complicated and your code base is small, you can still use MVC to meet your requirement.

Hope that helps.